# Unable to run the second scenario in cucumber feature with testng

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng

I have created maven project with cucumber as BDD , integrating it with testng . I have added 2 scenarios in my feature file . I have configured the runner class in my testng.xml and in my runner class I am launching the browser with @BeforeClass . The test successfully runs first scenario but does not run the second one . Please guide how to proceed ahead with this.

My Scenarios in feature file is :

```
Feature: Base PartyUserStories

  Scenario: Verify login
    Given the username and password
     When login is clicked 
     Then you enter the login page 

  Scenario: Verify login and blah blah 
    Given the username and password
     When login is clicked 
     Then you enter the login page
```

My Runner class is where I am calling the browser :

```java
@CucumberOptions(features = { "src/test/resources" }, glue = { "com.cucumber.testng.party.tests" })
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Runs always ");
    }

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void geturl() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https:test.aspx");      
    }        

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void quiturl() {        
        driver.quit();
    }

    @AfterTest        
    public void stoprun() {        
        System.out.println("Runs after every test");
    }      
}
```

This is my testng.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Party" parallel="none">
    <test name="Base Party Validation">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.cucumber.testng.runner.TestRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

It runs the first scenario successfully , for second scenario it doesn't launch the browser . Please help me with this .

Comment: Can you put the entire code of all the java files including App.java file

Answer (score 0):

Use the @Before @After hooks which run prior to each scenario 
to achieve this since you have a single feature file and multiple scenarios.

Comment: This solution works fine if i run the feature file , but on running the testng.xml as testng suite , I get nullpointer because the browser does not get launched.

Comment: What have you put in the testng xml?  You should be adding the runner as a test or class there and your annotated methods should be available in your glue folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [qaf bdd](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario.html) or [qaf gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) where driver management and configuration management done by framework. If you are new to automation you can walk through [qaf-step-by-step-tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki)